# Android toolbar menu items are invisible

Tags: java, android

For some reason items won't appear in the menu.They look fine in menu design folder but when i start the virtual device it's a blank area.But if i set the items as showAsAction,it works fine.

this is my menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/resim"
        android:title="Item1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item2"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item3"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:title="Item4"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and this is my java file

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolBar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);

        return true;
    }
}
```

here's what it looks like in design page

[image: design page appearance]

and here's how it looks like in the virtual device

[image: virtual device appearance 1]

[image: virtual device appearance 2]

what do you think is wrong with this?

edit:

here is my themes file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I disabled default toolbar and added a custom one.

and here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show us styles.xml and themes.xml files. How do you declare toolbar in layout xml? It looks like you are not theming the toolbar.

Comment: I edited my post and added those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a custom toolbar, change the main theme of the application to `NoActionBar`

```
 <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
       
       /..........

    </style>
```

also replace

```
android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
```

to

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Like this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

`anroid:theme` sets general style for toolbar.
`android:popupTheme` sets general style for popup.

---

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]